# SDK Manager CLI don't accept package_list option anymore?

Tags: android, sdk, command-line-interface

Since this morning, I can't run `sdkmanager --package_file=/sdk/packages.txt`. The version is `26.1.1`.

The response is:

```
Warning: Unknown argument --package_file=/sdk/packages.txt
Usage: 
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file=<file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --version
```

Is there a bug in `sdkmanager`?

I try a lot of way like:

- `sdkmanager --package_file="/sdk/packages.txt"`
- `sdkmanager --package_file "/sdk/packages.txt"`
- `sdkmanager --package_file /sdk/packages.txt`
- `sdkmanager /sdk/packages.txt`
- `sdkmanager "/sdk/packages.txt"`

But I can't running it...

Comment: The issue is already reported https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66465833